# enviar informacion de una variable desde otro activity

Tags: android, kotlin, app

tengo un activity1 que enviar una variable al activity2. uso un putExtra en el intent del activity1 y un bundle en el activity2.

```
btn.setOnClickListener{
        val goBtn = Intent(this, infoDB::class.java)
        goBtn.putExtra("info", info.text.toString())
        startActivity(goBtn)
    }
```

Luego en el activity2 tengo un adapter que se conecta a la Base de Datos para extraer informacion del usuario y filtrar la base de datos.

```
Class infoDB() : AppCompatActivity() {

val bundle = intent.extras
val info= bundle?.getString("info")

val db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()

val adapter = InfoAdapter(FirestoreRecyclerOptions.Builder<InfoA>()
    .setQuery(db.collection("user").whereEqualTo("info", info.toString()), InfoA::class.java).build(), this)
```

Finalmente el adapter es llamado mas abajo en el onCreate, en onStart y en onStop.

Si quito el whereEqualTo, la app me muestra toda la base datos y funciona muy bien, pero yo necesito filtrarla; pero al agregar la variable todo se va al carajo...

Agradecer la ayuda! Saludos!

Comment: has probado con esto ```info?.let {//codigo del adapter}```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`intent` retorna `null` si lo llamas antes del método `onCreate`. Al declarar la variable `val bundle = intent.extras` como miembro directo de la clase, se ejecuta durante la inicialización  y por lo tanto antes del `onCreate`. En otras palabras, estás llamando `null.extras` lo cual obviamente va a arrojar una `NullPointerException`.

Para solucionarlo debes hacer que esas variables tengan una inicialización lazy. Puedes hacerlo con la función `lazy` o con el modifier `lateinit`.

con `lazy`

```
class infoDB() : AppCompatActivity() {
    val db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()
    val info by lazy {
        intent.extras?.getString("info").toString()
    }
    val adapter by lazy {
        InfoAdapter(
            FirestoreRecyclerOptions.Builder<InfoA>()
                .setQuery(db.collection("user").whereEqualTo("info", info), InfoA::class.java)
                .build(),
            this
        )
    }
}
```

con `lateinit`

```
class infoDB() : AppCompatActivity() {
    val db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()
    lateinit var info: String
    lateinit var adapter: InfoAdapter

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        info = intent.extras?.getString("info").toString()
        adapter = InfoAdapter(
            FirestoreRecyclerOptions.Builder<InfoA>()
                .setQuery(db.collection("user").whereEqualTo("info", info), InfoA::class.java)
                .build(),
            this
        )
    }
}
```

o si unicamente necesitas la variable `info` para crear el adapter, declarala como variable local dentro de `onCreate`

```
class infoDB() : AppCompatActivity() {
    val db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()
    lateinit var adapter: InfoAdapter

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        val info = intent.extras?.getString("info").toString()
        adapter = InfoAdapter(
            FirestoreRecyclerOptions.Builder<InfoA>()
                .setQuery(db.collection("user").whereEqualTo("info", info), InfoA::class.java)
                .build(),
            this
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: ME SALVASTE :.... INCREIBLE !!!! muchisimas gracias ... tanto por la ayuda como por la explicacion !!! ... funciono muy bien =)